# When UAC popup comes screen recording stop with error "Failed to capture image (error 5)" in windows using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, uac

I am using `FFMPEG` for desktop recording it works fine in normal but when any `UAC POPUP` comes it stop working and exit with error  `Failed to capture image (error 5)` Is there any solution for overcome this error or any other suggestion.
Here is my string of ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -f gdigrab -video_size 800x600 -i desktop -vcodec h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -vsync vfr -b:v 1.5M -bufsize 2M -y d:\output.mp4
```

Here is the error when UAC popup appears

```
[gdigrab @ 0104e720] Failed to capture image (error 5)
desktop: I/O error
frame=  249 fps= 20 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1334kB time=00:00:12.75 bitrate= 857.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=1.01x
video:1332kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.153446%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] frame I:1     Avg QP:25.20  size: 72565
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] frame P:248   Avg QP:10.15  size:  5205
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  9.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:88.2%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.2% 33.4% 32.2% inter: 4.2% 5.3% 4.7%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 72% 26%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 20% 20%  1%
[libx264 @ 0276f3a0] kb/s:852.28
```

> Window 7 and advance all versions (administrative mode or simple both
>   in same) recent version of ffmpeg 3.4 on web and in cmd it shows

```
ffmpeg version N-86755-g0780ad9 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
libavutil      55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
libavcodec     57.100.104 / 57.100.104
libavformat    57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
libavfilter     6. 95.100 /  6. 95.100
libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
```

Comment: You don't indicate which version of FFMPEG you are using.  You don't indicate which version of Windows you are using.  You don't indicate if you run FFMPEG with Administrator permissions if anything changes.  Edit your question, include this information, do not submit this information as a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited .

Comment: What actual command are you using? Please show the command and its entire output, not just the error.

Comment: @slhck i have edited and put command and output as well.

Comment: Are you running ffmpeg as the same user as the one that is logged in?

Comment: @slhck yes i just open cmd and use the command for recording in Administrative mode and normal mode as well but same error

Answer (score -1):

You could disable UAC for the duration of the recording.

Comment: actually i cannot i want this pop because this ffmpeg is running on client side so i cannot low the security level of client's window

Comment: How you solved this problem ?